# How to stream video from ip camera with vlc

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, vlc

I need to translate video from ip camera with VLC to my site. I can save stream as file, but this is constantly growing file, with not actual video on start. I can also stream video via http as `http://myserver:8080`, but in this case i cant use this adress in my html tag

`<object data='http://myserver:8080' type="video/x-msvideo" width="300"
    height="100">  </object>`

How can i stream this video to my site?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the HTML5 `<video>` tag?

Such as:

```
<video controls>
<source src="/this/is/where/your/fileis.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: No, html5 is not avaible